# MariaDb master slave with failover

Tags: mariadb

I havea business need related to a MariaDb instance that should work in a master-slave configuration with failover.

Looking at the documentation I have seen that is possible to conigure a multi- cluster-master (galera) or a simple master slave replica.

Any suggestion to configure master-slave + failover?

Many thanks in advance
Roberto

Answer (score 5):

MySQL/MariaDB master-slave replication is great for handling read-heavy workloads. It's also used as a redundancy strategy to improve database availability, and as a backup strategy (i.e. take the snapshot/backup on the slave to avoid interrupting the master). If you don't need a multi-master solution with all the headaches that brings—even with MySQL Cluster or MariaDB Galera Cluster—it's a great option.

It takes some effort to configure. There are several guides out there with conflicting information (e.g. MySQL vs. MariaDB, positional vs. GTID) and several decision points that can affect your implementation (e.g. row vs. statement binlog formats, storage engine selection), and you might have to stitch various pieces together to form your final solution. I've had good luck with MariaDB 10.1 (GTID, row binlog format) and mixed MyISAM and InnoDB storage engines. I create one slave user on the master per slave, and I don't replicate the `mysql` database. YMMV. This [guide](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/setting-up-replication/) is a good starting place, but it doesn't really cover [GTID](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/gtid/).

Failover is a whole separate ball of wax. You will need some kind of a reverse proxy (such as [MaxScale](https://mariadb.com/products/mariadb-maxscale) or HAproxy) or floating IP address in front of your master that can adjust to master changes. (There might be a way to do this client-side, but I wouldn't recommend it.) Something has to monitor the health of the cluster, and when it comes time to promote a slave to the new master, there is a whole sequence of steps that have to be performed. MySQL provides a utility called [mysqlfailover](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqlfailover.html) to facilitate this process, but as far as I know, it is not compatible with MariaDB. Instead, you might take a look at [replication-manager](https://github.com/tanji/replication-manager), which seems to be MariaDB's Go-based answer to mysqlfailover. It appears to be a very sophisticated tool.

Comment: As far as I understand there is no a failover route that is simpler than galera cluster setup.

Comment: @RobertoG. You asked, "Any suggestion to configure master-slave + failover?" and I answered that question. Did you mean to ask a different question?

Comment: Some decisions are slam-dunk today:  binlog format `ROW`, `ENGINE=InnoDB`, MariaDB (since it has Galera builtin in and supported, not separately installed).  The new guy on the block, Oracle's Group Replication, is likely to be a strong contender soon.

Answer (score 1):

Master-Slave *helps* with failover, but does not provide it.

MariaDB Cluster (Galera) does provide failover for most cases, assuming you have 3 nodes.